# Is there a shortcut to make every field @Notempty in Spring annotation based validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I am using Hibernate Validation annotations

```
@NotEmpty
```

Is there a way to make all the fields of a form @NotEmpty which means i don't need to write @NotEmpty on top of all fields.

If possible how, and what are the limitations associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don`t know a Validation Annotation that works like you want, but I have an idea for an workaround:

Use **AspectJ Inter-Type declarations** to add the `@NotEmpty` annotation to every field in a Class that have marker annotation or is in an specific package.

I am not an AspectJ expert, but your Addvice should look like:

```
declare @field : * org.xyz.model.dto..* : @NotEmpty;
```

@See: [AspectJ Reference: Declare Annotation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-declare.html)